# Is free embed token app specific or user specific?

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

As mentioned in Power BI Documentation, 
"Embed tokens with PRO license are intended for development testing, so the number of embed tokens a Power BI master account or service principal can generate is limited".

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded-faq

**So my question is...**

If developer require more free tokens for testing app in developement environment, can he change master account to acquire more free tokens ? Embed token are app specific or user specific ?

Any comments are appreciated.
I am new to Power BI Embedded.

Comment: Pankaj, do you know how many tokens could be created with PRO license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options: You can switch to another account (master service account) if you reach the limit but you will incur the cost of another PowerBI Pro License. You can also work with Microsoft support to have your limited reached to meet your needs until you are production ready. You can reach Microsoft support by going here https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/support/ and scrolling down to "CREATE SUPPORT TICKET"

[image]

Note: If you are in Production you will have to buy a capacity. There is no way around that.

Comment: I have managed to get more free tokens by switching master account credentials. As my application is still used for testing & development purpose, this approach works for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @vvvv4d "Note: If you are in Production you will have to buy a capacity. There is no way around that." - what if you ran production on trial capacity and just replaced the user everytime you're close to hit the token limit. Is it legal? I can't find explicit deny of such behavior anywhere in the docs.